# Issue with Deleting Cookies using setcookie() in Plugin Development

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, setcookie

I am currently working on a plugin where I need to manage cookies. I have successfully set cookies using the setcookie() function, but I am encountering an issue when trying to delete a cookie using the expire parameter like this:

```
    setcookie('name', 'value', time() - 3600, '/'); or
    unset($_COOKIE['name'])
```

However, the cookie doesn't seem to get deleted as expected. I'm puzzled by this behaviour and would appreciate some guidance on how to properly delete cookies in my plugin.
I expect to learn what might be causing the issue with deleting cookies using the expire parameter in the setcookie() function. Additionally, I would like to understand the correct approach to delete cookies effectively within a plugin context. Any code examples or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `setcookie` with expiration date in the past, that's the trick. the reason is, when you set a cookie, it gets stored in a client browser; if you `unset` it from PHP (serverside) how will the client browser know that the cookie was unset?

Comment: hopefully, somebody else will be able to explain it as a proper answer

Comment: @GrafiCode i expire cookie with time()-3600 [1 hour past time] but not works

Comment: With the poorly provided code and fuzzy given explanations, nobody can guess by magic the root of the problem.. There are a bunch of related tutorials with code examples everywhere all over internet.